# See if 'root word' is within 'full word' using r

Tags: r, regex

I have data that looks as below:

```
 head(orthographic)
         Word   Root
 1     manful    man
 2     carful   care
 3  basketful basket
 4 meaningful   mean
 5     boxful    box
 6    armsful   <NA>
```

And I would like to see if `Root` word is within `Word`. For example, `man` is contained in `manful` and the spelling does not change. However, `car` changes to `careful`.

```
My ideal output
        Word   Root      C
1     manful    man     No
2     carful   care     Yes
3  basketful basket     No
4 meaningful   mean     No
5     boxful    box     No
6    armsful   <NA>     <NA>
```

What I have tried (based on others' postings):

```
a=orthographic$Word
b=orthographic$Root

df$a %in% df$b
charmatch(df$a,df$b)
grepl(df$a,df$b)
grep(df$a,df$b)
```

However, none of them gave me the output I want. Especially, all of the codes produced:

```
2     carful   care     "NO" # (Instead of "Yes").
```

I appreciate any input/solutions.

Comment: Your intent isn't completely clear. Are you trying to find out if a root is in a word? If so, then everything should be "Yes" except "care → carful", which should be "No" as "care" has nothing to do with "carful", which means "a car full of something". Or do you know that the roots are in the words, and you just want to check if they have been changed? If so, "care → carful" still isn't true.

Comment: Shouldn't `Yes` be `No` and the other round in the ideal ouput?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `str_detect` from `stringr`

```
df$C <- c("Yes", "No")[stringr::str_detect(df$Word, df$Root) + 1]
df$C[is.na(df$Root)] <- NA
df
#        Word   Root    C
#1     manful    man   No
#2     carful   care  Yes
#3  basketful basket   No
#4 meaningful   mean   No
#5     boxful    box   No
#6    armsful   <NA> <NA>
```

**data**

Keep data as characters and not factors.

```
df <- structure(list(Word = c("manful", "carful", "basketful", "meaningful", 
"boxful", "armsful"), Root = c("man", "care", "basket", "mean", 
"box", NA)), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, use an `ifelse` statement (credit to @Ronak Shah for the idea of using `str_detect`)

```
df$C <- ifelse(str_detect(df$Word, df$Root), "No", "Yes")
df
        Word   Root    C
1     manful    man   No
2     carful   care  Yes
3  basketful basket   No
4 meaningful   mean   No
5     boxful    box   No
6    armsful   <NA> <NA>
```